# align-items:center; not working as intended

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was just reading David's article **[HERE](https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center-flexbox)** and decided to give flexbox a try and so i made the following example of my own:

```
<div class="wrpr">

        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrpr {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid tomato;
    height: 300px;
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.wrpr div {
    background: #eee;
    height: 50px;
    width: 49%;
    margin: 0 .5%;
}

.wrpr div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #727272;
}
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ywvebu8x/1/)**

Now the annoying part is that the 4 div's are not exactly centered, but rather spaced out. why is that happening?

i believe this is a typical newbie problem, for someone migrating to flexbox, but i really can't find a solution to this issue.

can anybody help me understand why `align-items:center;` isn't working as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `align-content` to control multi-line spacing. `align-items` is for single-line use only. Add one line to your code:

```
.wrpr {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center; /* new */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ywvebu8x/4)

> [**align-content**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within
>   the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
>   similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
>   main-axis. ***Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex
>   container.*** (emphasis mine)

Comment: So you've used both `align-items: center;` and `align-content: center;` , thats the tick i believe ?

Comment: By including both you cover both bases: If there is only one line, then `align-items` will kick-in. If there are multiple lines, then `align-content` takes over.

Comment: In fact, `align-items` isn't necessary here.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn, correct. It's not necessary in this instance. However, I would suggest keeping it for a time when flex items may all be on one line (e.g., flex items are removed, or don't wrap, or whatever). Essentially, there is no downside in keeping it, but the downside of removing it could be significant.